# How to add and retrieve a CGpoint value into NSmutable dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

This is my code

```
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:10,y:10) let ns = NSValue(CGPoint: point) 
let dict:NSMutableDictionary = ["point":"\(ns)"] 
let getVal:CGPoint = (dict["point"] as? NSValue)!.CGPointValue()
```

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableDictionary`, you should use a native Swift dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
        let point = CGPoint(x:10,y:10)
        let point2 = NSPoint(x:20,y:10)
        var dict = [String : NSPoint ]()
        dict["point"] = point
        dict["point2"] = point2
        print(dict["point"])
        print(dict["point2"])
```

You can use CGPoint and NSPoint interchangeably in swift (NSPoint is OSX only as @OOPer pointed out)

Answer (score 0):

The better would be using Swift `Dictionary` rather than `NSMutableDictionary`. But if you have some reason you need to use `NSMutableDictionary`, you can store `CGPoint`s in a `NSMutableDictionary` like this.

```
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:10, y:10)
let ns = NSValue(CGPoint: point)
let dict:NSMutableDictionary = ["point": ns] //<- You should not use `"\(ns)"` hear!
if let val = dict["point"] as? NSValue {
    let cgPointVal = val.CGPointValue()
    print(cgPointVal) //->(10.0, 10.0)
}
```

Comment: @daven11, The OP is asking about `CGPoint`, and `NSPoint` is not available in iOS.

Comment: oh ok, he didn't actually mention iOS, but I can see your point - why not just store the CGPoint's then?

Comment: @daven11, that's another issue, as I noted "if you have some reason you need to use NSMutableDictionary", if it was me, I would use `[String: CGPoint]` rather than `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:10,y:10)
let dict:NSMutableDictionary = ["point":NSValue(CGPoint: point)]
let getVal:CGPoint = (dict["point"] as? NSValue)!.CGPointValue()
print(getVal)
```